# How to store pandas series to sql as a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I have a pandas `Dataframe` object, and I iterate through the rows with:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # do some stuff
    # save row to database
```

The problem is when I try to save it to database, `to_sql` treats my `row` as a *column*.

The variable `row` seems to be of type `Series`, and I did a careful search through the `Series.to_sql` in the manual, and I don't see any way of treating it as a database *row* instead of *column*.

The workaround I came up with is converting the `Series` to a `DataFrame` and then transposing it:

```
    temp = pd.DataFrame(row).T
    temp.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index_label='idx')
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why don't you just update the dataframe with the for loop and then call df.to_sql afterwards on the entire dataframe? This would be way faster than inserting the rows individually.

Comment: Because different information gets stored into different tables.

Comment: You probably just want to use your database driver to insert the row. pd.DataFrame.to_sql is really meant for tabular data

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use `df.iterrows`, which returns indices and a series representation of each row, one approach would be to iterate through `df.index` and use [integer-location based indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to slice the data frame for row manuipulation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
for i in range(df.index):
    row = df.iloc[i:i+1,:]
    #do Stuff
    row.to_sql(...)
```

This is the recommended way to modify to your dataframe.  From the `df.iterrows` docstring:

```
2. You should **never modify** something you are iterating over.
   This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the
   data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing
   to it will have no effect.
```